# How to warn about a duplicate values combination

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, duplicates, formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create the following warning in Google Spreadsheet:  when I add, in columns `Name` and `Date`, a combination of values which are already present then in the column `Result` I should receive the message `Duplicate date`.

Here is an example:

```
Name  | Date          | Result

Alex  | 27/11/2013  
John  | 28/11/2013  
Alan  | 29/11/2013  
Val   | 30/11/2013  
Jack  | 2/12/2013       
Alex  | 27/11/2013    |Duplicate date
```

I know how to raise a "warning" if a duplicated `Date` exists, by changing the ColumnC cell text "Date" into that message, but I don't know how to pair the `Name` and `Date` values. 
I use this =IF:

`=IF(COUNTA(B2:B)>COUNTA(UNIQUE(B2:B));"Duplicate date";"Date")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=If(ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A3)*(B:B=B3))>1);"Duplicate date";"")
```

in C3 and copied down (assuming `John` is in A4).

Note however this detects duplicates (ie both your first and last rows above, rather than merely the repetition that the last is of the first row).

Comment: I have returned with another question: how can I exclude the null fields? For example I have a n entire empty row and this will lead to "Duplicate date" appearing in the result.